# Calculate average value of all sorted array combinations

Tags: python, math, statistics, combinations, combinatorics

I need to get the statistical expected value of a n choose k drawing in a sorted array.

As an example, let's consider I want to choose 2 elements from the following sorted array

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

The set of all possible combinations is the following:

```
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
```

So the expected value of the first element is `(1 + 1 + 2) / 3 = 1.33`, and the expected value of the second element is `(2 + 3 + 3) = 2.67`

Here is a function that works with a bruteforce approach for doing that, but it is too slow to be used on large arrays.
Is there a smarter/faster way?

```
import itertools
import math
def combinations_expected_value(arr, k):
    sums = [0] * k
    l = math.comb(len(arr), k)
    for comb in itertools.combinations(arr, k):
        for i in range(k):
            sums[i] += comb[i]
    
    return [sums[i] / l for i in range(k)]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give some idea of the magnitude of the lists you need to process and the time taken with your code (which may not be optimal)

Comment: I'm guessing that you mean `1.33` rather than `1.67` for the expected value for the first element?

Comment: @MarkDickinson right, I edited the original post

Comment: @JCaesar worst case I need to handle is around k=200 and n=10_000
Right now, (n=300, k=4) takes 5mn, (n=300, k=5) is > 20mn which is not acceptable.

I should also add that right now I'm using an approximation where I just "split" the array in k parts and take the middle value of each part (which is not great when array values are not evenly distributed), so I'm open to approximations as well if there is no fast exact solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each position in the combination, the possible values are a subset of the list starting at the position and up to the last k-p-1 element. e.g. for combinations of 6 in 1..100, position 3 can only contain values 3..96

For each of the positon/value pairs, the number of occurrences will be the product of combinations of left side elements and combinations of right side elements.

For example, for combinations of 6 elements within a list of 1..100, the number of times 45 will appear at the third position is the combinations of 2 in 1..44 times the combinations of 3 in 46..100.  So we will have C(44,2) * C(55,3) * 45 for that positon/value pair.

You can repeat this calculation for each positon/value pair to obtain a total for each position in the output combinations.  Then divide these totals by the number of combinations to get the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value):

```
from math import comb

def countComb(N,k):
    result = [0]*k
    for p in range(k):                 # p is count on the left
        q = k-p-1                      # q is count on the right
        for i in range(p,len(N)-q):
            left  = comb(i,p)          # combinations on the left >= 1
            right = comb(len(N)-i-1,q) # combinations on the right >= 1
            result[p] += left * right * N[i]
    return result
            
def combProb(N,k):
    Cnk = comb(len(N),k)
    return [S/Cnk for S in countComb(N,k)]
```

Output:

```
print(countComb([1,2,3],2)) # [4, 8]
print(combProb([1,2,3],2))  # [1.3333333333333333, 2.6666666666666665]

print(countComb([1,2,3,4,5],3)) # [15, 30, 45]
print(combProb([1,2,3,4,5],3))  # [1.5, 3.0, 4.5]

# test with large number of combinations:

print(countComb(list(range(1,301)),7))
[1521500803497675, 3043001606995350, 4564502410493025, 
 6086003213990700, 7607504017488375, 9129004820986050,
 10650505624483725]

print(combProb(list(range(1,301)),7))
[37.625, 75.25, 112.875, 150.5, 188.125, 225.75, 263.375]
```

Comment: Do you need the `if p else 1` and `if q else 1` parts? `math.comb(i, 0)` will always be `1` for nonnegative `i`.